# URL doesn't show in LaTeX

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I would like to reference an online reference. I am using this code:

```
@ONLINE{a4,
      title  = "Correlation, Confidence Interval, and Sample Size",
      author ={millercommamatt},
      url    = {http://millercommamatt.com/journal/index.php/2008/02/19},
      year   = "2008 (accessed November 25, 2013)"
    }
```

but I see only something like this:

[image]

but not the URL, what should I do?

Comment: What do you have as `\bibliographystyle`?

Comment: \bibliographystyle{ieeetr}

Comment: That bibstyle doesn't know the URL field. Maybe you can use `note="\url{http:...}"` (needs the `hyperref` or `url` package).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `ieeetr` bibstyle doesn't know the field `url`; it doesn't know the type `online` either, but this is a minor problem.

With

```
@misc{a4,
  title  = {Correlation, Confidence Interval, and Sample Size},
  author = {millercommamatt},
  note   = {\url{http://millercommamatt.com/journal/index.php/2008/02/19}},
  year   = {2008 (accessed November 25, 2013)},
}
```

you solve both issues. Remember to have `\usepackage{url}` if you don't have `\usepackage{hyperref}`.

Minimal example.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{a4,
  title  = {Correlation, Confidence Interval, and Sample Size},
  author = {millercommamatt},
  note   = {\url{http://millercommamatt.com/journal/index.php/2008/02/19}},
  year   = {2008 (accessed November 25, 2013)},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}
\cite{a4}
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]